# Return row address when specific cells are filled

Tags: excel, vba, cell, worksheet-function

I have some code that will return the row address when any of the column C:C is filled.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Target.Cells
        If Not Intersect(c, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Range("A" & c.Row).Value = c.Address
        
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

How would I go about adding to this code so that it would only occur when adjacent C:D:E cells are filled in any order? So if a value was added in C5 then D5 and then E5 it would return 5:5 as the row address but only after all 3 of those cells have values, if only C5 and D5 were filled it wouldn't fire.

Comment: What have you tried adding to the code to implement your idea? Where did you run into trouble with it? Please include that in your question.

Comment: Hint: `Application.Worksheetfunction.counta("C:" & c.row & ":E" & c.row)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Worksheet Change

- Copy the code to the appropriate sheet module e.g. `Sheet1` (the tab name is in parentheses).

```vb
Option Explicit

' When done studying, out-comment or delete all the 'Debug.Print' lines
' except the one in the error-handling routine.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Use an error-handling routine to prevent exiting without enabling
    ' events in case of an error.
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    Const fRow As Long = 2
    Const cCols As String = "C:E"
    Const dCol As String = "A"
     
    Dim crg As Range
    Set crg = Columns(cCols).Resize(Rows.Count - fRow + 1).Offset(fRow - 1)
    Debug.Print "crg: " & crg.Address(0, 0)
    Dim irg As Range: Set irg = Intersect(crg, Target)
    
    If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Debug.Print "irg: " & irg.Address(0, 0)
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Intersect(irg.EntireRow, crg)
    Debug.Print "srg: " & srg.Address(0, 0)
    
    ' I'm guessing that this is a too short operation since using
    ' the following line makes it kind of slow.
    'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Disable all events when writing to prevent retriggering the code.
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    Dim arg As Range ' Area Range
    Dim rrg As Range ' Area Row Range
    Dim RowString As String ' Current Row
    
    For Each arg In srg.Areas
        Debug.Print "arg: " & arg.Address(0, 0)
        For Each rrg In arg.Rows
            ' If the cell contains a fromula evaluating to ="",
            ' 'CountA' will count it. 'CountBlank' will consider it blank.
            If Application.CountBlank(rrg) = 0 Then
                RowString = CStr(rrg.Row)
                RowString = "'" & RowString & ":" & RowString
                rrg.EntireRow.Columns(dCol).Value = RowString
                Debug.Print "rrg: " & rrg.Address(0, 0) & " - " & RowString
            End If
        Next rrg
    Next arg

SafeExit:
     
    If Not Application.EnableEvents Then
        Application.EnableEvents = True ' enable all events when done writing
        'Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' too short operation
    End If
    
    Exit Sub ' don't forget this

ClearError:
    Debug.Print "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & Err.Description
    Resume SafeExit
End Sub


' Run this in VBE and see the results in the Immediate window ('Ctrl+G')
' Note that this is writing to a non-contiguous range (multi-range) which
' you can manually only copy, but it will be pasted contiguously.
' For this to work, 'Areas (arg)' is used as an additional complication.
Sub TestMultiRange()
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("C2:E4,C6:E6,C8:E10")
    rg.Value = "Test"

' Result in the Immediate window if all three-cell ranges are not blank:
'crg: C2:C1048576
'irg: C2:C4,C6,C8:C10
'brg: C:E
'srg: C2:E4,C6:E6,C8:E10
'arg: C2:E4
'rrg: C2:E2 - '2:2
'rrg: C3:E3 - '3:3
'rrg: C4:E4 - '4:4
'arg: C6:E6
'rrg: C6:E6 - '6:6
'arg: C8:E10
'rrg: C8:E8 - '8:8
'rrg: C9:E9 - '9:9
'rrg: C10:E10 - '10:10
End Sub
```

Comment: So I'm starting to get it (even if slowly). I just want to understand a few things, irg = Intersect(crg,Target)  looks like it would work when information is entered into C but it doesn't do anything. And how come even though the code states columns C:E it only works when information is either input into all columns at once or into E then D then C. Why does it not populate regardless of in which order the data is entered into those 3 columns?

Comment: Because I didn't understand correctly what you wanted. So you want this to happen whenever C, D, or E are entered and only if C, D, and E, all of them, are not empty. Right? If so, I will need a few minutes to rewrite this. Please do confirm and add if something else is imporatant.

Comment: That's exactly correct, I'm still trying to learn VBA, your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've corrected the code.

Comment: Brilliant that works perfectly, now to understand how it works :D